# Need help reading/writing ECDSA Keys in GoLang

Tags: go, encryption, ecdsa

Currently, I have:

```
// generate keys
priv, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)
// get public key
pub := priv.Public()
```

I, however, need help on getting the raw byte data and using the correct encoding to read/write these public and private keys to files.

Comment: What file format do you want?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Honestly, any file format that I can easily write it to and read from (EG: Text, JSON, YAML, XML, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Just marshal them to a `[]byte` using `x509.MarshalECPrivateKey`.  You can just read and write the binary to a file.

You might find in future you want to store the keys in PEM format, as is common.  You can do that with the `encoding/pem` package.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance!